# create CollaborationGroup in SandboxPostCopy Class

Tags: sandbox-refresh, sandboxpostcopy, automated-process, collaborationgroup

Anyone have experience in creating a CollaborationGroup using SandboxPostCopy class ? My requirement is to create a Public Group in newly refreshed sandbox.
**I have tried following ways but no success:**

Owner = (no value assigned)i.e., Automated Process User (autoproc)
CollaborationType = Public
Error = System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, This user can’t be added to the group.: []

Owner = <*active_admin_user*>
CollaborationType = Public
Error = System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, This user doesn’t have permission to own groups. : [OwnerId]

assigning Method run() with @Future
OwnerId = <*active_admin_user*>
CollaborationType = Public
Error = method didn’t execute, hence no Collaboration Group created.

Owner = <*active_admin_user*>
CollaborationType = Private
Error = System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, This user doesn’t have permission to own groups. : [OwnerId]

Apex Class:

```
global without sharing class PrepareMySandbox implements SandboxPostCopy {
global void runApexClass(SandboxContext context) {

    createChatterGroup();
}

global static void createChatterGroup() {
    User adminUser = new User(); // user having profile = System Administrator
    adminUser = [SELECT ID, username FROM User where isActive = TRUE AND username like 'admin@domain.com%' LIMIT 1];
    CollaborationGroup OppForNetSuiteGroup = new CollaborationGroup(
        Name = Test.isRunningTest() ? 'Test Group' : 'My Group Name',
        Description = 'Some Group Description',
        CanHaveGuests = FALSE,
        CollaborationType = 'Public'
        OwnerId = adminUser.ID
    );

    insert OppForNetSuiteGroup;
}
```

}

Test Class

```
@isTest
public with sharing class PrepareMySandboxTest {

static testMethod void test_createChatterGroup(){
    
    Test.startTest();
        Test.testSandboxPostCopyScript(
            new PrepareMySandbox(),
            UserInfo.getOrganizationId(),
            UserInfo.getOrganizationId(),
            UserInfo.getOrganizationName());
        
        CollaborationGroup findChatterGroup = new CollaborationGroup();
        findChatterGroup = [SELECT Name, Owner.username from CollaborationGroup where Name = 'Test Group' LIMIT 1];
        system.assertEquals(findChatterGroup.Name, 'Test Group');
    Test.stopTest();
    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

There is an Idea to include chatter groups sandbox refresh. https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000Gdf4QUAR/include-chatter-groups-in-sandbox-refresh-to-avoid-pb-errors

There you will find a comment with a code example, how the user solved this problem. Maybe you can use that code and make it work for you.

Comment: Already tried the code available there, before posting Query here ! It doesn't work.

Comment: I am sorry. But I have no further ideas

Answer (score -1):

The documentation says

> The SandboxPostCopy Apex class is executed at the end of the sandbox copy using a special Automated Process user that isn’t visible within the org. This user doesn’t have access to all object and features; therefore, the Apex script cannot access all objects and features. If the script fails, run the script after sandbox activation as a user with appropriate permissions.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_System_SandboxPostCopy.htm

Comment: if that is the case, then why don't @future worked ?

Comment: What do you mean by that? Try to run the code as another user. For Example as you from the debug console.

Comment: I know that while running the code as me in Developer Console is working fine. What I meant is "I tried annotating the method with @Future" in SandboxPostCopy class and it didn't work (refer my #3 scenario in question).</br >
</br >
@Future</br >
global static void createChatterGroup()</br >

Comment: how is the sharing defined in your apex class? with sharing or without sharing. When it is not seht to wihtout sharing it will run in the user context. In this case the user who executes the sandboxpostCopy class, does not have all permissions. It does not matter if it is a future method or not

Comment: I have used both "without sharing" including "at-Future" method and without "at-Future" method. It doesn't work and throws the same error "System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, This user doesn’t have permission to own groups. : [OwnerId]"

Comment: For me it looks like the (SandboxPostCopy) user does not have the permission to own a group. It would be great if your would edit your post with the whole apex class. I think the future method is not needed.
Make sure the user who is the owner(OwnerId) of the group hast the permission 'Create and Own New Chatter Groups'

Comment: I have tried using owner as 'Automated Process User' & 'System Administrator Profile - User'. both doesn't work.
Added the Code as well now in my Original Post.

I somehow started to think that, the system mode for 'Automated Process User' is not equivalent to system mode for 'non Automated Process User'

Comment: I do not think it has something to do with your code. I think it has something to do with permissions. 1. Have you checked if your admin profile has the permission 'Create and Own New Chatter Groups'? 2. is your test class working= If so. Can you also share the code from your test class?

Comment: The user 'admin@domain.com%' has standard profile 'System Administrator' and has system permission 'Create and Own New Chatter Groups'

Comment: Does your admin user has a valid email address? Remove the .invalid from the email address and try again. Maybe you have to remove the .invalid in your postCopy class before creating the chatter groups

Comment: This user email is correct without .invalid, because this is the same user who is refreshing sandbox from Production.